# Prove $E[N]=E[\Lambda]$ and $\operatorname{Var}[N]=\operatorname{Var}[\Lambda]+E[\Lambda]$

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability

I am self studying mathematical statistics and am struggling with the following problem.

Let $N\sim \operatorname{Poi}(\Lambda)$ where $\Lambda$ is also a random variable. Show that $$E[N]=E[\Lambda]$$ and $$\operatorname{Var}[N]= \operatorname{Var}[\Lambda]+E[\Lambda]$$

Here is what I have tried so far.

$$E[N]=E[E[N\mid\Lambda=\lambda]]=E[\lambda]$$

I am confident so far due to the $E[E[X\mid Y]]$ fact, and that $N$ is Poisson $\lambda$.

However, I am not confident that I assumed $\Lambda=\lambda$ so $E[\Lambda]$ is the answer because for if it is true, then $E[\Lambda]=\lambda$ since $\lambda$ is a constant although we have no information regarding what kind of distribution $\Lambda$ is.

The next part is even more iffy for me.  I know that

$$\operatorname{Var}[N]=\operatorname{Var}[E[N\mid\Lambda=\lambda]]+E[\operatorname{Var}[N|\Lambda=\lambda]]$$

so,

$$\therefore = \operatorname{Var}[\lambda]+E[\lambda^2]$$

which does not make sense since  I am trying to prove the identity.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: If $X$ has [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with parameter $\lambda$ then it variance equals $\lambda$ (not $\lambda^2$ as you seem to think).

Comment: You are totally right, for some reason my mind was exponential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning the [conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation) we have the rule:$$\mathbb EX=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\mid Y]]$$Applying that here gives:$$\mathbb EN=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[N\mid \Lambda]]=\mathbb E\Lambda$$

Concerning [conditional variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_variance) we have the rule:$$\mathsf{Var}X=\mathbb E[\mathsf{Var}[X\mid Y]]+\mathsf{Var}[\mathbb E[X\mid Y]]$$

Applying that here gives:$$\mathsf{Var}N=\mathbb E[\mathsf{Var}[N\mid \Lambda]]+\mathsf{Var}[\mathbb E[N\mid \Lambda]]=\mathbb E\Lambda+\mathsf{Var}\Lambda$$

Comment: Just by curiosity on the notation since I saw it several times before. Is there a reason to write $\mathbb E N$ instead of $\mathbb E [N]$ or is it just for reducing notations complexity ?

Comment: @P.Quinton There is no particulier reason for that. Just a matter of taste.

Comment: I was thinking that, too.  The first time I encountered (actually, paid attention to) expected values it was in exam P from the actuarial exams and the text book used $E[X]$

Comment: @drhab Just for confirmation, then.  If the distribution of N was Exp$(\text{mean}=B)$, where B is a random variable, then would the following be true?

$$Var[N]=E[B^2]+Var[B]$$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @drhab Thank you!